# Take picture in android lollipop programmatically

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I am developing an app which can take a picture (front camera) just by pressing a button. The app works fine on Android API level 10 and 15 but when I try that in Android Lollipop I get the force close error.

Here is my code:

```
private void takePicture() {
    openCamera();
    //System.gc();
    camera.startPreview();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            camera.takePicture(
                    new ShutterCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onShutter() {
                            // TODO Do something when the shutter closes.
                        }
                    }, new PictureCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {

                        }
                    }, new PictureCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {
                            // TODO Do something with the image JPEG data.
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(_data, 0, _data.length);
                            imgPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            Toast.makeText(TakePhotoActivity.this, "Length = " + _data.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
                            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + File.separator + "test.jpg");

                            // remember close de FileOutput
                            try {
                                f.createNewFile();
                                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                                fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                                fo.close();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            CloseCamera();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Update: 
I found this but still I don't know what to do:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html

Comment: Where is your LogCat error? you are saying that it crashes but you don't show up the LogCat... makes no sense :)

Comment: I cant test my app in debug mode because eclipse can not recognize my phone with android lollipop. I just can use another android device with API 10 which works fine.

Comment: What phone are you trying to use?

Comment: I use samsung galaxy tab A .

Comment: try to download [this driver](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117)

Answer (score 0):

in Lolipop and above things have changed , your crush probably is a securityException because you need to ask a permission from the user to use his camera or access to his gallery , to do this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) is google documentation that explain all with how to implement'it.